# instance variable which point to the AppDelegate will cause memory management issues?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, appdelegate

My colleague told me that using a instance variable which point to the AppDelegate
will cause something like retain cycle. I just want to know will doing that result in
some memory management issues.

Comment: There should be no problem having an instance variable point at the AppDelegate, since it lasts for the life of the app.  You only have a potential problem when the object containing the pointer may (absent that pointer) persist longer than the thing pointed to.

Comment: @HotLicks so the class which contains the instance variable which point to the AppDelegate can been dealloc correctly

Comment: *Containing* a pointer (of any flavor) will not prevent an object from being deallocated.